# How can I convert a ttyrecord file in a .gif file?

Tags: tty, conversion, gif

Using [`ttyrec`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ttyrec/) I can record any console program (`ttyrec`  invokes  a shell and records the session until the shell exits). The record is saved by default in a `ttyrecord` file and can be played using `ttyplay ttyrecord` command.

Now, I want to convert this `ttyrecord` file in a `.gif` file. I found [this phyton script (tty2gif.py)](https://bitbucket.org/antocuni/tty2gif/src/61d5596c9165/tty2gif.py), but, no matter how I do, I can not manage to make it to work...

Any other solutions will be appreciated!

Comment: Hello Radu Rädeanu. I don't have any ttyrec files for now but. Do you mind providing a download link for a sample in order to run some testing? Thank you.

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo
 You can obtain quickly one file by running 'ttyrec' in terminal. As I said the record will be in one 'ttyrecord' file in the current directory. To install it, run 'sudo apt-get install ttyrec'.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that. I didn't know. Sorry. And I have dropped a workaround as an answer in the hope that it may work for you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have ran a test with the `tty2gif` script that you mentioned on your question and I -somehow- succeeded getting the gif animation as shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

I needed to install python-opster in order to make the script work without a problem, otherwise you may receive a "`Line 7 Error`" message when running the script from the terminal. Then simply `sudo apt-get install python-opster` in the terminal, provide your user password and get the complement installed.

Now, if you run the script with no parameters you'll see the options as shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

We'll send the script's command with the "typing" option in order to get the individual gif shots as follows:

[image]

This will reproduce your keypresses in the terminal and will get an individual screenshot for each iteration. Which will result in several gif images in the folder, the images will be named "step???.gif" as seen in the next screenshot:

[image]

Now, we will use the convert command from the Imagemagick package in order to drop the next line in the terminal so that we can get a one-file gif animation made from these `step???.gif` image files, as follows:

```
convert -delay 50 -loop 0 *.gif terminal.gif
```

Please note that I am using *.gif having in mind that there are no other .gif files in the same folder, otherwise they may be merged in the resulting animation.

Here you can change the `-delay` and the `-loop` parameters, the same as the resulting filename.

You can also import these `step???.gif` files in gimp or any other image manipulation program in order to make a better (optimized) gif animation which will result in a smaller file size.

Please let us know if you succeed with this workaround or if you are experiencing a different kind of an issue, don't hesitate to let us know also.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get [tty2gif](https://bitbucket.org/antocuni/tty2gif/src/61d5596c9165/tty2gif.py) to work with vim so I hacked together [ttygif](https://github.com/icholy/ttygif).

[image: gif]

more detailed instructions can be found in the project [readme](https://github.com/icholy/ttygif/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Can you improve your answer?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu added an example.